# How to change the cell width of an exported jupyter notebook as html?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I exported my .ipynb with jupyter notebook as html.
When using the build-in export in jupyter-notebook via "File" -> "Export as" -> "HTML", the cells become infinite wide which can look very bad when there are images included within some markdown cells.
Naturally, jupyter-notebook has a limited cell width by default, which I also like to have within the exportet html.

This is an example how it looks like in jupyter notebook:
[image]

And this is how it looks like when opening the exported html file in any viewer or browser:
[image]

Is there any option to limit the cell width for the exported html either directly within jupyter or manually afterwards? Note: I need to use an .html export since I want to be able to interact with some bokeh figures directly in the file afterwards.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: I would think this is more a "superuser" question